# php cURL login to a website with javascript() on submit

Tags: javascript, php, curl, header

After a few hours of research and trials, I must ask for help .
I have this scenario : I want to use cURL to login to a website, but I get the login page everytime . 
The login page is very simple, with just 2 input forms and a button .
I must say that the button has a javascript event OnSubmitDonStuff() ... but I used TamperData to look at the headers .. and here is my code :

```
$post_data = array();
$post_data['action'] = "login";
$post_data['email'] = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
$post_data['password'] = "mypass"; 
$postthis = http_build_query($post_data);

//URLS
$host = "passwordwebsite.com";
$url = "http://passwordwebsite.com";
$loginReferer = "http://passwordwebsite.com";
$reputationUrl = "http://passwordwebsite.com/dashboard";

// The User-Agent string to send
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";
// Create temp file to store cookies 
$cookieJar = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookiez_.tmp';
// URL to login page 

// Create the cURL handle for login
$ch = curl_init();

// Set connection meta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postthis); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

// Set header-related options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $loginReferer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);

// Set connection meta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // debug headers sent

$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1 ); //stop if an error occurred

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $reputationUrl); 

$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );

// Execute the request
if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
    exit("ERROR: Reputation scrape request failed: " . curl_error($ch));
}

// Output the result
echo $result;
```

The result is still the login page, and here are the headers I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 08:09:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Location: /
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 08:09:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: ps_auth=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=passwordwebsite.com; httponly
```

Comment: What is in `$cookieJar` variable? Have you tried login onto that webpage with disabled JS?

Comment: $cookieJar var contains the cookie file path, it's set above in the code.

The JS is not the problem as the redirects do get followed .. it's something wrong with the curl config ... or maybe with the server .. that's the thing .. I can't figure it out ...

Comment: Sorry, missed that, just wanted to know if it is absolute path, which it is. With disabled JS I meant, if you can login onto website, with your browser, without JS enabled? Does site support login without JS? Can you give us the link of the website?

Comment: that was a good question .. but NO, it does not fire without the javascript call .. I don't know why, but I did try and disabled JS .. and as expected it does not work .

Comment: Now you found the problem. Try to fake/crack this JS login. Good luck with that ;)

Comment: well cURL should follow all redirects ...

Comment: In your pasted headers, redirect has happened, and followed, like `Location: /`. Thats why you get second response header.

Comment: got it working ! after forking with it, on a redirect I found a link that accepted the POST data and loged me in .